# Why is subpath() throwing IllegaArgumentException in this case?

Tags: java, directory, illegalargumentexception

I'm writing an app for folder synchronization. I have two dir structures, Source and Target, and I need to somehow refer to the eqivalent file/folder in the other dir structure when recursing through the other. This method attempts to achieve that by first extracting the sublocation of the file in Source by lobbing off the root folder that was previously selected by the user and stored as a global variable and then appending it to the root folder of Target, which is likewise user selected and stored globally. Why isn't this working? The arguments seem fine; from the length of the sourcePath to the index of the last element.

```
private Path getEquivalentFileInTarget(Path pathOfSource) {
    Path sourceSublocation = pathOfSource.subpath(sourcePath.getNameCount(), -1);
    return targetPath.resolve(sourceSublocation);
}
```

Error log:

```
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1771)
    ... 48 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPath.subpath(WindowsPath.java:634)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPath.subpath(WindowsPath.java:44)
    at sample.FolderSyncerMainWindowController.getEquivalentFileInTarget(FolderSyncerMainWindowController.java:133)
    at sample.FolderSyncerMainWindowController.putInTreeViewCompare(FolderSyncerMainWindowController.java:120)
    at sample.FolderSyncerMainWindowController.handleCompareButton(FolderSyncerMainWindowController.java:92)
... 58 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are misusing `Path`.

Now, I don't know whether your different `Path`s are issued from different file system providers, but *if they are not* you can just do that:

```
final Path subpath = sourceRoot.relativize(fullPathInSource);
final Path fullPathInTarget = targetRoot.resolve(subpath);
```

This will also work if `subpath` is the empty path (this is what `sourceRoot.relativize(sourceRoot)` will return).

Comment: Why are you using that "final" there?

Comment: Pure coding habit; if a variable is declared final, I know it cannot be reassigned anywhere else in the scope

Answer (score 1):

The second parameter of `subpath` method must be a number that is strictly greater than the first parameter, because it's an index of the subpath element. There is no situation when it would be allowed to be negative.

You should subtract `1` from the count, like this:

```
Path sourceSublocation = pathOfSource.subpath(0, sourcePath.getNameCount()-1);
```

Comment: "The name that is farthest from the root has index count-1" So that's what that "count" thing means... Well, so much for skimming over the documentation instead of thoroughly reading it and making sure I understand *every* word.

Answer (score 1):

From [the documentation website](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html#subpath(int,%20int)):

```
Path subpath(int beginIndex,
           int endIndex)
```

> Parameters:beginIndex - the index of the first element,
>   inclusiveendIndex - the index of the last element, exclusive
>
> Throws:IllegalArgumentException - if beginIndex is negative, or
>   greater than or equal to the number of elements. If endIndex is less
>   than or equal to beginIndex, or larger than
>    the number of elements.

and since `endIndex` must be larger than `beginIndex` and the `beginIndex` must be larger than zero then the `endIndex` must also be larger than zero and you passed -1